# How to obtain admin rights android app

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an app for only one run, it picks some files and when this process is finnished I would like uninstall the app automactlly.

I was reading about that and without admin rights is not possible.

How can I obtain this admin Rights?

It's possible download an admin rights app from PLay Store?

Greetens

Comment: So it scans for some files, reads them, and silently uninstalls itself? That doesn't sound shady *at all*.

Comment: The only way you, as a third party developer, can do this on "Android" is to launch an uninstall Intent, which will have to be confirmed by the user.  Anything else relies on your users having a customized version of Android with atypical security policies, or you being the publisher of the version of Android installed on the device.

Comment: Hi Chris, How can I ask the user for ask and grant this admin privileges when they install my app?

Answer (score 1):

> I was reading about that and without admin rights is not possible.

You would need to have root privileges to "uninstall the app automactlly".

> How can I obtain this admin Rights?

You are welcome to try to root your device. This is off-topic for StackOverflow. But, there are many sites on the Internet, and one may have instructions for rooting your particular device. Of course, it would be simpler for you to just uninstall the app from your device manually.